# How to use ng-click value as ng-repeat property?

Tags: angularjs

How to get `$scope.clickedVal` in `r.clickedVal`?

Button click calls a function, passing in two parameters:

```
<a ng-click="display('Info', 'Admission_Info'); filters.Admission_Info= '!!'; ">Info</a> 
<a ng-click="display('Info', 'SomeOther_Info'); filters.SomeOther_Info= '!!'; ">Other</a>
```

Function in the controller:

```
$scope.display = function (col, val) {
  $scope.filters = {};
  $scope.clickedColumn = col;
  $scope.clickedVal = val;
};
```

Table displays a filtered view with 2 columns.

```
<tr ng-repeat="r in response | filter:filters as filtered " ng-show="filtered.length">
  <td>{{ r.Name }}</td>
  <td>{{ r.clickedVal }}</td>
</tr>
```

`{{ r.{{clickedVal}} }}` didn't work.

So for example, if the first button is clicked, `r.clickedVal` should return `r.SomeOther_Info`.

I've tried creating a filter as well but run into the same issue - `m.value` is incorrect.

```
SchoolProgramsApp.filter('myFilter', function () {
    return function (input, column, value) {
        var out = [];
        angular.forEach(input, function (m) {         
            if (m.value === value) {           
                out.push(m)
            }    
        })    
        return out;
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't follow.  You have a scope variable called `response` - what does that look like?  Your `ng-click` sets some other scope variable, and I'm not seeing the connection between it and `response`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to access property of the object by variable name:

```
{{ r[clickedVal] }}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick and helpful response.